# I have to count till 45 with increments of 3 using for loop only in python

Tags: python

I have to count till 45 with increments of 3 using for loop only in python. I did it using while loop but I want to do it without the while loop?

```
for n in range(1):
    while n < 45:
        n = n + 3
        print(n)
```

Comment: It seems you didn't find the documentation for `range`. [Here it is](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#range).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) function with `start` `stop` and `step` parameters

```
for i in range(3,46,3):
    print(i)
```

OUTPUT

```
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
24
27
30
33
36
39
42
45
```

Comment: I think OP wants to start from `3`. So use `range(3,46,3)`

Comment: @codester_09  that would make more sense... I changed it